# Unable to add new Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Can't properly add a new version of Tomcat Server.

```
IDE: Eclipse Luna (64 bit)
Server: Tomcat 8.0.30 (64 bit)
Java: jdk1.8.0_65 (64 bit)
```

[image]

Comment: I think u have preconfigured tomcat 8 before so first please remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following step and Eclipse allowed me to add new tomcat.

```
Step 1: In {workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings delete the following two files:
          i. org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
         ii. org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
        iii. Restart Eclipse

Step 2:  Delete the tomcat: Server > right click delete.
         i. New server installation:
        ii. Server > right click > tom 8.0 > next > finish.
       iii. Start the server.
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows->preference->servers->Runtime Envirorments.
In this location remove all the pre-configured tomcat 8 and later try to add new one

Comment: I have removed previous tomcat-8 entry from Runtime Environments but still unable to add new tomcat-8.